# Sum of variable changing over time (AMPL)

Tags: sum, ampl

I have a time dependent variable that changes with some predefined timesteps. I would like get the sum of the variable over the course of several timesteps. How can I write the sum of the variable?

.mod file:

```
set Time default {}; #number of timesteps
param top{Time}; #number of hours in each timestep
var E{Time}         >= 0.001; #the timedependent variable

subject to annualElectricity{t in Time}: 
    Ea = sum{E[t]*top[t]};
```

.dat file:

```
set Time := 1 2 3 4 5 6;

param top := #operating time (hours)
1 609
2 321
3 532
4 425
5 351
6 7
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `annualElectricity` constraint collection that you have declared is your attempt to do what you want, but I'm not sure you want to use a constraint for that.

If you want to sum all variables in the collection `E`, the sum expression will be `sum{t in Time} E[t]`. If you want the sum of all products `E[t]*top[t]`, the sum expression will be `sum{t in Time} E[t]*top[t]`.

If you won't need this value to solve the problem, you can declare a `param Esum` and then, after you have solved the problem, you can call `let Esum := sum{t in Time} E[t]`. But if you need this value in your problem, I believe you can define a variable `var Esum = sum{t in Time} E[t]` and use it in your constraints/objective function.

I can see you are new to AMPL, so you may benefit from reading some basic AMPL introduction, such as this https://pifop.com/help/ampl_programs.html that I've written.